# Javascript + Emoji strangeness

Tags: javascript, emoji

I'm trying to do some string methods with some text that has Emoji embedded inside of it.

However, this is a very strange thing I have seen:

```
"".length == 2
```

I'm just wondering how it decides what appears as 1 character to me, is actually 2.

Comment: Sadly, JavaScript does not fully support Unicode (believe it or not) due to historial reasons. Here's a good article on that: [JavaScript and Unicode](http://blog.jochentopf.com/2011-03-17-javascript-and-unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks. That article has cleared it up a bit, I'm working around it by ensure I calculate the length of the characters

Answer (score 0):

> In Javascript, a string is a sequence of 16-bit code points. Since emoji > are encoded above the BMP, it means that they are represented by a pair > of code points, also known as a surrogate pair.
> So for instance, 0x1F600, which is , is represented by:
>
> > "\uD83D\uDE00"

If you're willing to go further on this, you can read this article: [Emojis in Javascript - Parsing emoji in Javascript is… not easy.](https://medium.com/@thekevinscott/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb#.q27so0927)